# Samsung Galaxy S3 and HTC Sensation use the wrong layout file

Tags: android, layout, size, screen, dimension

Both Samsung Galaxy S3 and HTC Sensation fit the category of layout-sw360dp.

Galaxy s3 > (720/320) x 160 = 360

Sensation > (540/240) x 160 = 360

However, when I try creating a layout folder layout-w540dp-h960dp. It does not read from it and instead it reads from the folder layout-sw360dp.

How to prevent this and make each load within its specific layout ? and why layout-w540dp-h960dp does not work ?

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: @Budius my post is edited. please have a look.

Comment: @CoreyScott can you be more specific please ?

Comment: @CoreyScott there is something which does not make sense in the second answer also. It is suggested to use layout-sw720dp (which I did and in the presence of layout-sw360dp folder, it was still unread, and even though layout-sw720dp would not work as S3 is xhdpi device.)

Do you have any suggestions/hints/solutions ? I need to make Sensation and S3 on different layouts.

Comment: Edit: removed "chat" comments and copied last comment from answer #2, seems i was wrong, its working as intended. "The Galaxy S3 is a xhdpi device, so you have to divide a pixel-based dimension by 2 to get the dimension in dp. So the S3 is 640dp tall, and 360dp wide. – navale Oct 19 '12 at 7:57"

Comment: @CoreyScott how does this help me ? Are you getting my question ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `layout-sw<N>dp` has got higher precedence than `layout-w<N>dp`.

In Android, resources folder qualifiers are selected according to a specific precedence rules. Have a [look at this table](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2). It specifies all the available configuration qualifiers which can be used for providing alternative resources.

According to that table `layout-sw<N>dp` has got higher precedence than `layout-w<N>dp`. So if there is a conflict arises, Android always selects the highest configuration qualifier.

Here both your devices can take resources from `layout-sw360dp`. So both devices use the same folder for selecting resources.